# pandas: dropping columns based on value in last row

Tags: python, pandas

Starting out with data like this:

```
np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':[pd.date_range('2016-04-01', '2016-04-05')[r] for r in np.random.randint(0,5,20)], 
        'cat':['ABCD'[r] for r in np.random.randint(0,4,20)], 
        'count': np.random.randint(0,100,20)
})

   cat  count       date
0    B     84 2016-04-04
1    A     95 2016-04-05
2    D     89 2016-04-02
3    D     39 2016-04-05
4    A     39 2016-04-01
5    C     61 2016-04-05
6    C     58 2016-04-04
7    B     49 2016-04-03
8    D     20 2016-04-02
9    B     54 2016-04-01
10   B     87 2016-04-01
11   D     36 2016-04-05
12   C     13 2016-04-05
13   A     79 2016-04-04
14   B     91 2016-04-03
15   C     83 2016-04-05
16   C     85 2016-04-05
17   D     93 2016-04-01
18   C     32 2016-04-02
19   B     29 2016-04-03
```

Next, I calculate totals by `date`, pivot `cat` into columns, and calculate running totals for each column:

```
summary = df.groupby(['date','cat']).sum().unstack().fillna(0).cumsum()

cat            A    B    C   D
date
2016-04-01    80  235   99   0
2016-04-02    85  295  153  14
2016-04-03   111  363  224  14
2016-04-04   111  379  296  50
2016-04-05   111  511  296  50
```

Now I want to remove columns where the last column is less than some value, say 150.  The result should look like:

```
cat          B    C 
date
2016-04-01   235   99 
2016-04-02   295  153 
2016-04-03   363  224 
2016-04-04   379  296 
2016-04-05   511  296
```

I've figured out one part of it:

```
mask = summary[-1:].squeeze() > 150


       cat
count  A      False
       B       True
       C       True
       D      False
```

will give me a mask for dropping columns.  What I can't figure out is how to use it with a call to `summary.drop(...)`.  Any hints?

Comment: I got different values.  Did you get those immediately after generating the seed?

Comment: Does this return the filter you desire: `mask.index.get_level_values(1)[mask]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of dropping the columns you do not want, you can also select the ones you want (using the mask with boolean indexing):

```
In [16]: mask = summary[-1:].squeeze() > 220

In [17]: summary.loc[:, mask]
Out[17]:
            count
cat             B      D
date
2016-04-01  141.0   94.0
2016-04-02  235.0   94.0
2016-04-03  235.0  144.0
2016-04-04  326.0  144.0
2016-04-05  384.0  229.0
```

(I used 220 instead of 150, otherwise all columns were selected)

Further, a better way to calculate the mask is probably the following:

```
mask = summary.iloc[-1] > 220
```

which just selects the last row (by position) instead of using squeeze.